# PHP For loop to generate dynamic images

Tags: php, zend-framework, mongodb

I have a page that will need to generate thumbnail images for each article. The number of thumbnails will vary for each so I want to check the article in the database and create an array for all of the thumbnails but i'm struggling with the logic.

This is what I have so far:

```
for ($i=1; $i<20; $i++) {
  $thumbImages = array(
    'src' => $newblogDoc['tvs']['thumbnail-image-' . [$i]]
  );
}
```

Is this the right direction? Is there a more efficient way to put this into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear but if you want to make an associative array of arrays then you need to do:

```
for( $i=1; $i<20; $i++){
$thumbImages[] = array(
                'src' => $newblogDoc['tvs']['thumbnail-image-'.[$i]]
                );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have right now is overwriting $thumbImages with a new array each time. What you want to do is create a new array before the loop, and then append to that inside the loop. As so:

```
$thumbImages = array();
for ($i=1; $i<20; $i++){
    $thumbImages[] = $newblogDoc['tvs']['thumbnail-image-'.[$i]];
}
```